# Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit after-installation help

Tags: installation, 12.04, boot, graphics, 64-bit

I installed Ubuntu 12/04 64 bit on my desktop using the Nomodeset on boot screen. After the CD finished installing it asked me to restart, I hit restart button, my CD pops out so I take it out and close the DVD drive. When my computer restarted on boot screen it got all purple and warped looking and just sits there like that. Please help, I think it's my gfx card but I don't know what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding nomodeset to the default boot again.  After the BIOS screen finishes on your computer press `Esc` quickly and then scroll to the kernel you want to boot.  Add `nomodeset` to the end of the line which starts with "linux" and then boot.

If that works you'll want to make it permanent in which case you have to edit the default grub file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

add `nomodeset` to end of the line which starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` then type `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Your first step worked perfectly, now where do I type in the 'sudo gedit /etc/grub' to make nomodeset permanent?

Comment: @user60194 Yes, labama's answer is correct. If you need something explained in more detail just search around. This topic is repeatedly asked & answered. For example, you can try the second part of [**this answer**](http://askubuntu.com/a/19487/52923) which I thought laid out the steps fairly well.

Comment: in any terminal or if you running gnome-shell or unity press `Alt-F2`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had the same problem. However, the file to edit seems to be /etc/default/grub, not /etc/grub

Comment: @RolfSander Of course you're right, I could've sworn that's what I had typed initially, but there are no other edits so the blame can only fall on me...