# Ubuntu 12.04 boot hangs with a black screen before grub menu after upgrade (gma500_gfx driver)

Tags: grub2

I am using Ubuntu on a fit-pc2 [specifications](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/fit-pc/fit-pc2-specifications/) and after upgrading from 10.04 to 12.04 I get a black screen at boot time (before displaying the grub menu) and the computer hangs with no disk activity.

I have managed to boot Ubuntu 12.04 on a live USB key but had to add the following boot options to do so:

- console=tty1 or console=text
- acpi=off
- noapic
- nomodeset

Using boot-repair, I have tried to add these options to /etc/default/grub (see [this pastie log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/974136/) for instance) but I haven't been able to fix the black screen issue.

I have tried many other things such as the workarounds mentioned on the web for PSB-GFX_drivers without any success and also to uncomment `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` with the result of getting a

> No video mode activated

error.

During these tests, I have managed to break /boot/grub/grub.cfg and could then hit grub in command line. This gave me the chance to check that I can boot without problem if I type:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 ro acpi=off noapic nomodeset console=tty1
grub> initrd /initrd.img
grub> boot
```

How can I tell grub to use these options?

Comment: I had the same problem. This helped me:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/131125/ubuntu-12-04-64-bit-after-installation-help

Comment: Hmmm... there is no such file as /etc/grub in grub2 and this should probably read /etc/default/grub. If that's the case, I have tried this already and that doesn't work in my case.

Comment: What I really don't understand is that if I replace the content of /boot/grub/grub.cfg by the grub commands shown above the machine boots perfectly well but when I add the same kernel options in /etc/default/grub they seem useless.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/425556/grub-freeze-debian-ubuntu-home-server) with my own fitpc2 and it works.

You need to select "Windows XP", not "Other OS" in the bios settings.

Answer (score 0):

After editing `/etc/default/grub` did you run `sudo update-grub`?

It doesn't update until you do that.

Comment: Yes, the bootinfo that is attached is after running update-grub.

Answer (score 0):

My screen lost connection after BIOS had been loaded, I went into BIOS and saw that it was put to DOS and WinXP. I tried switching both to other but nothing worked. I then put it back to DOS and kept the other and it booted with graphics. It works!

Answer (score 0):

You can check your kernel options by checking the output of `dmesg`. Look for a line that starts with `[0.000000] Kernel command line:` . It might not be right at the start, as an example mine is line 145 this boot.