# Problem with Wubi installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, wubi

I am getting a black screen with the following message when I reboot my PC after the installation via Wubi. I tried again and again but still I get this screen and then it's stuck.

```
Message : 
pwconv: failed to change the mode of etc/passwd- to 0600
Shadow passwords are on.
Generating locales...
```

And it continues for a few more lines and then stops.

What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Probably it's a graphic card issue. Try using `nomodeset`: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 (post #8 has some wubi specific instructions - look at Method 2; otherwise see post #1)

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is based on [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc)'s [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209712/problem-with-wubi-installation#comment260626_209712).*

This appears to be a graphics card issue. So try [using the `nomodeset` boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132).

First try [post #8](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10089820&postcount=8), Method 2 (summarized as follows):

1. In windows open `X:\ubuntu\install\wubildr-disk.cfg` in a text editor, where **`X:`** is the drive where you installed Wubi.
2. Add `nomodeset` to the end of the line that looks like:

   ```
   linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk preseed/file=/ubuntu/install/preseed.cfg wubi-diskimage ro quiet splash
   ```

   So this line will now be:

   ```
   linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk preseed/file=/ubuntu/install/preseed.cfg wubi-diskimage ro quiet splash nomodeset
   ```

If this doesn't work, press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you select Ubuntu in the boot menu. If [a GRUB menu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) comes up, you'll need to use [the instructions for installed, non-Wubi systems](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10069997&postcount=1) (see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131125/ubuntu-12-04-64-bit-after-installation-help)).